# Use if first statement in a single variable is SAS

Tags: sorting, sas

Hello: I have a question.
I have a sas dataset like this:

```
data a;
input id $ a b ;
cards;
ddd 12  1
ddd 22  1
ddd 44  2
ddd 50  1
ddd 52  1
ddd 88  2
;run;
```

and I expect I can use  if first to flag the obs lake this:

```
data a;
input id $ a b flag $;
cards;
ddd 12  1  Y
ddd 22  1  
ddd 44  2  Y
ddd 50  1  Y
ddd 52  1  
ddd 88  2  Y
;run;
```

In order to do that, I sort the dataset by ID, a,b and tried to use if first.b to create flag. But it flags all the obs with Y. I think it might be the reason that I sort by a before b. But in order to keep the dataset in this order, I have to sort it by a,b.  So, my question is how can I keep the order and use first.b to create the flag?
Thanks.

Comment: Include your code if you want help with why it doesn't work.

Comment: Also - in your examples, the dataset is sorted `by id a b` but could be also considered valid to say it is sorted `by id b` - is that going to be true in your larger dataset, or can b change in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using `set by a b;` in combination with `first.b`.  The reason `first.b` doesn't work in this case is because `first.b` will be true for the first value of b *inside* an a group, and in this case there is only one b within each a.

This alternative should work, it retains the previous value of b and checks it each time.

```
data flagged (drop=prev_b);
 set a;
 retain prev_b;
 if b ne prev_b then flag='Y';
 output;
 prev_b=b;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to figure out how to get the last obs in the same logic, but still no clue. Do you think we can apply it by the same logic?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `NOTSORTED` option on the `BY` statement so that SAS will set the FIRST. and LAST. flags as want them.

```
data want ;
  set a ;
  by id b notsorted;
  flag = first.b ;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: That's wonderful, and exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!